# Prevent Downloading of Mobile Safari Video

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, video-streaming, quicktime

Via HTTP Live Streaming or any other method, is it possible to embed videos in a web page that:

1. Are viewable in Mobile Safari?

   and
2. Cannot be directly downloaded? (when the user navigates to the media URL in a browser, they should not by default get a downloadable file.)

Flash and Silverlight can serve media that meet these criteria on desktop browsers. I'm wondering if there's some way to meet this criteria that is compatible with Mobile Safari, which does not support Flash or Silverlight. The media need not be impossible to rip, just difficult to download with a browser alone.

For example, on the below site, demonstrating HTTP Live Streaming, I can just open up the video URLs and do File > Save. This is what I (actually the client's legal team) would like to avoid.

http://iphone.akamai.com/

Edit: Tried to clarify my question based on responses so far.

Comment: According to me, my answer would have been same as @PARTH's answer. You do not have control over behavior of things outside your IPhone application.

Answer (score 1):

its known fact that anything accessible to a browser is downloadable, otherwise the browser couldn't get it. most users are to busy watching the video to think about downloading it, but if they want it there get it...

Comment: Edited my question, hopefully it's more clear. Ultimately anything served to a computer can be captured by that computer (by screen caps or a camcorder pointed at the screen, if nothing else.) I'm just wondering if it can be made non-trivial in this particular case.

Comment: its not screen recorders or camcorders its the firefox plugins like DownloadHelper(i use this) or Ant Video Downloader that make it super easy to download the media as user is notifid when an embedcode is detected with a single click kinda thing. just think if it was possible to stop downloading youtube would employ it.

Comment: it could be possible if the stream was encrypted like dvd css for flash lol, then the player hold the key to decrypt the stream but then the player would be hacked for the key and a converter made...

Answer (score 0):

@dleavitt:

As per Apple's HIG, It is a fact that an app cannot have control of the things outside its sandbox.

So as the Mobile Safari Browser is not in the sandbox of any of the iPhone/iPad apps, it cannot be controlled. You cannot modify or make any changes into its default behaviour.

So keeping it in simple words, You cannot stop downloading videos via Mobile Safari Browser as you dont have control over it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to build an iPhone app that messes with Safari though, I'm trying to serve streaming media in a way that's accessible to mobile Safari, but somewhat protected from downloading.

Comment: @dleavitt: But you can't control mobile Safari's behaviour. So you can't stop user from downloading. Once the your media stream appears in Safari, it is out of your control. Then it behaves as per default behaviour of mobile Safari. Hope this makes it more clear. :-)